# белые картинки tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

я делаю свою программу на python используя customtkinter и я сделал элемент CTkTabview и при добавлении картинок туда они почему-то белые но без Tabview всё хорошо ниже картинки с и без Tabview прошу помочь т.к не знаю как решить данную проблему
вот код с CTkTabview:

```
    #tab
tabview = customtkinter.CTkTabview(root, width=580)
tabview.place(x=10, y=30)
#tabview.set("tab 1") #set currently visible tab
tab_1 = tabview.add("не вышедшие игры")
tab_2 = tabview.add("доп")

button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(tab_2, text=1)
button_1.pack()
#Картинки мегаигр
GTA6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="gta6.png")
GTA6_Lb = Label(tab_1, image=GTA6, bd=0)

MINE2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="MineCraft.png")
MINE2_Lb = Label(tab_1, image=MINE2, bd=0)

RDR3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="RDR3.png")
RDR3_Lb = Label(tab_1, image=RDR3, bd=0)

WITC4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="WITCHER4.png")
WITC4_Lb = Label(tab_1, image=WITC4, bd=0)

HF3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="HF3.png")
HF3_Lb = Label(tab_1, image=HF3, bd=0)

pizzabut = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=tab_1, text='Заказать пиццу',
fg_color='#1d1c70',
hover_color='#111045',
corner_radius=12,
font=("Arial-Bold", 15, "bold"),
command=pizza)
#виджеты
pizzabut.place(x=430,y=250)
GTA6_Lb.place(x=16,y=40)
MINE2_Lb.place(x=132, y=40)
RDR3_Lb.place(x=248, y=40)
WITC4_Lb.place(x=364, y=40)
HF3_Lb.place(x=482, y=40)
```

[image: с проблемой]
[image: без проблемы]

Comment: пунктуация, в частности запятые, являются частью письма и необходимы для выражения мыслей точно также, как буквы

Comment: CTkTabview не является стандартным виджетом Tkinter и может не поддерживать отображение изображений с помощью виджета Label

Comment: вы можете попробовать использовать виджет Canvas для отображения изображений вместо виджета Label

Comment: попробуйте https://pastebin.com/6AaZBNi2

Comment: Скорее всего сборщик мусора картинки удаляет из-за того, что вы их никуда не сохраняете после передачи в Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вместо label добавил CTkLabel и у меня получилось корректно отображать картинки. В документации у CTkLabel нет параметра image поэтому я и не пробовал использовать CTkLabel